# How to generate a netCDF weather forecast for a missing day based on yesterdays forecast?

Tags: dataset, data-cleaning

as can be seen here [met.no](https://eur01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fthredds.met.no%2Fthredds%2Fcatalog%2Fbarents25km_files%2Fcatalog.html&data=05%7C02%7COdd.Torbjorn.Karvand%40dnv.com%7C06c0f3fb98554e9b7c0c08dc16a7ccff%7Cadf10e2bb6e941d6be2fc12bb566019c%7C0%7C0%7C638410157158049509%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=lNgDpjuxcnqHkwINzagafX0VChjCTzSxrWU%2F60ZyoxM%3D&reserved=0), the forcast is missing for 20210823.
This forcast for each day is a 66 hour forecast, mening it will cover the next "missing" day.

Not knowing much about netCDF files (.nc?), how can I use the 20210822 file to generate the 20210823 file?

- Which tool can i use? Notepad++? Databricks?
- What parameters need to change in the file itself, and how do i go about to change them?